# i am using simple-peer and and can't display remote stream in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, peerjs, simple-peer

```
function callPeer(id: string) {
    const peer = initializePeerInstance({ initiator: true, stream: stream! });
    peer.on("signal", (data: any) => {
      socket.current.emit("callUser", {
        userToCall: id,
        signalData: data,
        from: yourID,
      });
    });
    peer.on("stream",  (stream: any) => {
      if (partnerVideo.current) {
        partnerVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
      }
    });
    socket.current.on("callAccepted", (signal: any) => {
      setCallAccepted(true);
      peer.signal(signal);
    });
  }
  function acceptCall() {
    setCallAccepted(true);
    const peer = initializePeerInstance({ initiator: false, stream: stream! });
    peer.on("signal", (data: any) => {
      socket.current.emit("acceptCall", { signal: data, to: caller });
    });
    peer.on("stream",  (stream: any) => {
      if (partnerVideo.current) partnerVideo.current.srcObject = stream;
    });
    peer.signal(callerSignal);
}
```

i have to functions: callPeer and acceptCall but when on('stream') is triggered i succesfully get stream and can set it to ref.current.srcObj but the video that accepts this ref doesn't display anything.
It works in Firefox but not in Chrome or any other browser, i have no idea where is the problem.
Tried different approaches to set video.srcObj=stream but not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i a try to add video to  <video
          playsInline
          muted
          width={400}
          height={400}
          ref={partnerVideo}
          autoPlay
        />, and it works in Firefox, but not in other browsers.